# Getting an RDD of Failure[T] from an RDD[Try[T]] without compilation warning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, try-catch, rdd

I have an `RDD[Try[T]]` and I want to trasnf`RDD` that contains only the element of type `Failure[T]`, which means all the element for which the method `isFailure` returns `true`. By now, I found the following solution.

```
rows.filter(row => row.isFailure)
    .map {
      case Failure(e) => // Do something...
    }
```

*Warning:(11, 36) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Success(_)
  map {*

Is there any method to obtain the same result without incurring in the compilation warning?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the first glance it looks like `collect` would be a better fit here:

```
rows.collect {
  case f @ Failure(e) => f
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always forget about the `collect` method!

Comment: Or slightly simpler `case f: Failure[_]`.